# Please let me know optimization tips for this insert query for faster execution

Tags: sql

Please help me to rewrite below insert query optimize.
My `stored procedure` contains these type of bunch of insert queries here I wants to make the `stored procedure` execution faster with replacing

```
INSERT INTO [allassetsurveyreport] 
SELECT Replace(srno, 'string;#', '') AS SRNO, 
       'Yes'                         AS Responded, 
       'Yes'                         AS IsOldReport, 
       NULL                          AS [Status], 
       [pleaserateyour_x00]          AS [Overall Satisfaction], 
       [easeofuse]                   AS [Ease of Engaging], 
       responsiveness                AS Professionalism, 
       [qualityofthedeliverable]     AS [Quality of Document], 
       NULL                          AS BulkUploadReason, 
       NULL                          AS [Requested FY], 
       NULL                          AS [Requested FM], 
       NULL                          AS Vertical, 
       NULL                          AS Industry, 
       NULL                          AS PrimaryContact, 
       NULL                          AS [Topic for Proposal] 
FROM   [rfx_survey]
```

Comment: which database is this? What are the indexes like on the tables?

Comment: Assuming `rfx_survey` is a table and not a view, the `insert` should be pretty fast.  The only thing faster would be a bulk insert, but the overhead in setting that up might actually slow things down.

Comment: If you call this stored procedure for every record, think about doing the inserts directly.

Comment: Show please in some fashion what the store procedure is doing (write a simplified version of it) or something like that to give us a clue what are you doing with this

Answer (score 0):

My answer only works if the table into which you insert this data, has default values for all the columns in which it says NULL or 'Yes' and all the other values are taken directly from the second table.

Then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO [allassetsurveyreport]  
     ([Overall Satisfaction], 
      [Ease of Engaging],
      Professionalism, 
      [Quality of Document])
SELECT [pleaserateyour_x00]          AS [Overall Satisfaction], 
       [easeofuse]                   AS [Ease of Engaging], 
       responsiveness                AS Professionalism, 
       [qualityofthedeliverable]     AS [Quality of Document]
FROM [rfx_survey]
```

I am not sure if the AS is necessary if you select the columns in the right order.

Comment: Listing the columns explicitly is a really, really good idea.  However, it should not affect the performance of the query.